# AVAudioSessionRouteChange Audiokit crashes when Bluetooth connection is turned on / off

Tags: ios, bluetooth, avfoundation, audiokit

I am using AVFoundation / AudioKit in order to record the internal microphone of the iPhone / iPad. It should be possible to continue using the app after switching the output between BluetoothA2DP and the internal speaker. The microphone should continue to take the input from the internal microphone of the device. And it does. Everything is working fine but only until I want to change the output device.

```
func basicAudioSetup(){

    // microphone
    self.microphone = AKMicrophone()

    // select input of device
    if let input = AudioKit.inputDevice {
        try! self.microphone?.setDevice(input)
    }

    AKSettings.sampleRate = 44100
    AKSettings.channelCount = 2
    AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true
    AKSettings.enableRouteChangeHandling = false
    AKSettings.useBluetooth = true
    AKSettings.allowAirPlay = true
    AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true
    AKSettings.audioInputEnabled = true


    // init DSP

    self.dsp = AKClock(amountSamples: Int32(self.amountSamples), amountGroups: Int32(self.amountGroups), bpm: self.bpm, iPad:self.iPad)


    self.masterbusTracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(self.dsp)
    self.mixer.connect(input: self.masterbusTracker)

    self.player = AKPlayer()
    self.mixer.connect(input: self.player)


    self.microphone?.stop()
    self.microphoneTracker = AKAmplitudeTracker(self.microphone)
    self.microphoneTracker?.stop()
    self.microphoneRecorder = try! AKNodeRecorder(node: self.microphone)
    self.microphoneMonitoring = AKBooster(self.microphoneTracker)
    self.microphoneMonitoring?.gain = 0
    self.mixer.connect(input: self.microphoneMonitoring)

    AudioKit.output = self.mixer

    // the following line is actually happening inside a customized AudioKit.start() function to make sure that only BluetoothA2DP is used for better sound quality:
    try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: [.defaultToSpeaker, .allowBluetoothA2DP, .allowAirPlay, .mixWithOthers])

    do {
        try AudioKit.start()
    }catch{
        print("AudioKit did not start")
    }



     // adding Notifications to manually restart the engine.

     NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.audioRouteChangeListener(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVAudioSessionRouteChange, object: nil)

}

@objc func audioRouteChangeListener(notification:NSNotification) {

    let audioRouteChangeReason = notification.userInfo![AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReasonKey] as! UInt

    let checkRestart = {

        print("ROUTE CHANGE")

        do{
           try AudioKit.engine.start()
        }catch{
           print("error rebooting engine")
        }

    }

    if audioRouteChangeReason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.newDeviceAvailable.rawValue ||
        audioRouteChangeReason == AVAudioSessionRouteChangeReason.oldDeviceUnavailable.rawValue{

        if Thread.isMainThread {
            checkRestart()
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: checkRestart)
        }

    }

}
```

I noticed, that when the microphone is connected, AVAudioSessionRouteChange is never called when switching from the internal speaker to Bluetooth. I do receive messages when starting with and switching from Bluetooth to the internal speaker:

> [AVAudioEngineGraph.mm:1481:Start: (err = PerformCommand(*ioNode,
>   kAUStartIO, NULL, 0))

What does this message exactly mean? I tried everything, from manually disconnecting all inputs of the engine / de- and reactivating the session to rebuilding the whole chain. Nothing works.

Theoretically the input source is not changing, because it is staying on the input of the phone. Any help highly appreciated.

*FYI: I am using a customized version of AudioKit library where I removed its internal Notifications of AVAudioSessionRouteChange to avoid unwanted Doppelgaenger. This customized library also sets the session category and options internally for the same reason and to ensure, that only BluetoothA2DP is used.*

Comment: Have you found a workaround for this issue?